# Insert Values Into SQL from a List OR Array Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I need to insert values into a table with from another select statement with multiple results. However, it is not like I can do it one by one. Is there any method that more efficient to insert values into the table?

> SELECT DISTINCT KID FROM K_Table

| KID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 7 |
| 15 |
| ... |

From the First DISTINCT SELECT Statement, it will select the multiple KID results which the results might be up to 100 rows.

```
INSERT INTO K_Table VALUES(Listof(KID)[0],'Default','ABC',GETDATE()),  
                            (Listof(KID)[1],'Default','ABC',GETDATE()),
                            (...)
```

Is that able to get the result from a SELECT statement and make it as array OR List for insert values purpose?

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres) ?

Comment: Sorry for missing tag for the SQL Type, it will be SQL Server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insert into .. select..` directly as follows:

```
INSERT INTO K_Table 
Select distinct KID,'Default','ABC',GETDATE()
  From k_table;
```

But, I dont know why you want to add data to same table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT with SELECT in one statement

`INSERT INTO K_Table(Kid, Col1, Col2, Col3) SELECT  DISTINCT Kid, 'Default', 'ABC', Getdate()  FROM K_Table`